# Filebeat not starting in windows

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Facing problem with staring up the Filebeat in windows 10, i have modified the filebeat prospector log path with elasticsearch log folder located in my local machine "E:" drive also i have validated the format of filebeat.yml after made the correction but still am getting below error on start up.

**Filebeat version :** 6.2.3

**Windows version:** 64 bit

**Filebeat.yml (validated yml format)**

```
filebeat.prospectors:
-
    type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
        - 'E:\Research\ELK\elasticsearch-6.2.3\logs\*.log'
filebeat.config.modules:
    path: '${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml'
    reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
    index.number_of_shards: 3
setup.kibana:
    host: 'localhost:5601'
output.elasticsearch:
    hosts:
        - 'localhost:9200'
    username: elastic
    password: elastic
```

Filebeat Startup Log:

```
E:\Research\ELK\filebeat-6.2.3-windows-x86_64>filebeat --setup -e
2018-03-24T22:58:39.660+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:468    Home path: [E:\Research\ELK\filebeat-6.2.3-windows-x86_64] Config path: [E:\Research\ELK\filebeat-6.2.3-windows-x86_64] Data path: [E:\Research\ELK\filebeat-6.2.3-windows-x86_64\data] Logs path: [E:\Research\ELK\filebeat-6.2.3-windows-x86_64\logs]
2018-03-24T22:58:39.661+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:475    Beat UUID: f818bcc0-25bb-4545-bcd4-3523366a4c0e
2018-03-24T22:58:39.662+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:213    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 6.2.3
2018-03-24T22:58:39.662+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:145     Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-03-24T22:58:39.665+0530    INFO    pipeline/module.go:76   Beat name: DESKTOP-J932HJH
2018-03-24T22:58:39.666+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:97   Starting metrics logging every 30s
2018-03-24T22:58:39.666+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:145     Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-03-24T22:58:39.672+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:690     Connected to Elasticsearch version 6.2.3
2018-03-24T22:58:39.672+0530    INFO    kibana/client.go:69     Kibana url: http://localhost:5601
2018-03-24T22:59:08.882+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:583    Kibana dashboards successfully loaded.
2018-03-24T22:59:08.882+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:145     Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-03-24T22:59:08.885+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:690     Connected to Elasticsearch version 6.2.3
2018-03-24T22:59:08.888+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:301    filebeat start running.
2018-03-24T22:59:08.888+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:108      Loading registrar data from E:\Research\ELK\filebeat-6.2.3-windows-x86_64\data\registry
2018-03-24T22:59:08.888+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:119      States Loaded from registrar: 5
2018-03-24T22:59:08.888+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:48   Loading Prospectors: 1
2018-03-24T22:59:08.889+0530    INFO    log/prospector.go:111   Configured paths: [E:\Research\ELK\elasticsearch-6.2.3\logs\*.log]
2018-03-24T22:59:08.890+0530    INFO    log/harvester.go:216    Harvester started for file: E:\Research\ELK\elasticsearch-6.2.3\logs\elasticsearch.log
2018-03-24T22:59:08.892+0530    ERROR   fileset/factory.go:69   Error creating prospector: No paths were defined for prospector accessing config
2018-03-24T22:59:08.892+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:109  Stopping Crawler
2018-03-24T22:59:08.893+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:119  Stopping 1 prospectors
2018-03-24T22:59:08.897+0530    INFO    log/prospector.go:410   Scan aborted because prospector stopped.
2018-03-24T22:59:08.897+0530    INFO    log/harvester.go:216    Harvester started for file: E:\Research\ELK\elasticsearch-6.2.3\logs\elasticsearch_deprecation.log
2018-03-24T22:59:08.897+0530    INFO    prospector/prospector.go:121    Prospector ticker stopped
2018-03-24T22:59:08.898+0530    INFO    prospector/prospector.go:138    Stopping Prospector: 18361622063543553778
2018-03-24T22:59:08.898+0530    INFO    log/harvester.go:237    Reader was closed: E:\Research\ELK\elasticsearch-6.2.3\logs\elasticsearch.log. Closing.
2018-03-24T22:59:08.898+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:135  Crawler stopped
2018-03-24T22:59:08.899+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:210      Stopping Registrar
2018-03-24T22:59:08.908+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:165      Ending Registrar
2018-03-24T22:59:08.910+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:308    filebeat stopped.
2018-03-24T22:59:08.948+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:132  Total non-zero metrics  
2018-03-24T22:59:08.948+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:133  Uptime: 29.3387858s
2018-03-24T22:59:08.949+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:110  Stopping metrics logging.
2018-03-24T22:59:08.950+0530    ERROR   instance/beat.go:667    Exiting: No paths were defined for prospector accessing config
Exiting: No paths were defined for prospector accessing config
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this path `${path.config}/modules.d/`
or check by command line "filebeat.exe modules list", if some modules are active, which do not work with windows.

For instance the *system.yml* (module) does not run on plain windows, because there is no syslog. But the system module is active by default. So you have to disable it first.
If I have it enabled, I run in the exactly the same error message, and filebeat stops.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the first part of the yml using this format:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*
```

Remove also the empty new line and take attention to the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this topic is a bit old however looking at the amount of views that this has received at the time of posting this (June 2019), I think it would be safe to add more informations as this is fairly frustrating to get while very easy to fix.

Before I explain what I did, allow me to say I had this problem on a Linux system but the problem/solution should be the same on all plateforms.

After having updated the **logback-spring.xml** and restarted the service, it kept refusing spitting back the following error:

```
 ERROR   instance/beat.go:824    Exiting: Can only start an input when all related states are finished: {Id:163850-64780 Finished:false Fileinfo:0xc42016c1a0 Source:/some/path/here/error.log Offset:0 Timestamp:2019-06-13 09:15:35.481163602 -0400 EDT m=+0.107516982 TTL:-1ns Type:log Meta:map[] FileStateOS:163850-64780}
```

My solution was simply to edit the **/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml** and comment as much stuff as I could (Going back to nearly a vanilla/basic configuration).

After having done so, restarting filebeat worked and this ended up being a duplicate path entry with another file somewhere in the system, possibly under the modules.